# React Native Auto Linking NEVER HAPPENS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, package.json

Well I am currently making a react native app and something is getting me really angry, as the title says everytime I install a package in react native that needs linking NEVER works and I really do not know why,and because I am using the latest version of the framework,manual linking with the `react-native link` command is not an option because it does not exist anymore,react native is so confident about their quality that they destroyed my unique option of help.

I dont know if it will help but this is the package.json of my CRUD app :

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.5",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.9",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.12",
    "axios": "0.27.2",
    "native-base": "^3.4.25",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-fontawesome": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-sweet-alert": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.26.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.4",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.8",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

> PS:many of the dependencies listed here like fontawesome or webview I still cannot use because it says that they are undefined and need manual linking (but how am I supposed to do it react native I ask you????)

By the way thanks for reading until here !

Comment: Facing the same issue. Not able to add any package on RN 0.70, auto-linking is not happening.

Comment: Hi ! Well I solved this little problem in a tricky way,I deleted node_modules and after ran `yarn install` and inside android directory ran `./gradlew clean` and it magically solved .... hope this works for you!!!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still facing issues.

Comment: Im sorry to hear that... did you try to change your Node or React Native version ? It solved some of my problems when changing these

Comment: By the way...the node version who works for me with RN is 16.0.0 (you can use it with ǹvm`)

Comment: And also the React Native version I use is `0.70.6` (it is not the latest but it is the one who fortunately works with me)

Comment: By the way I recommend you do these version changing tests in a separate project of yours (or you do a copy of it and test in it) just to be sure no problems will happen